# "Long-standing conjectures in analysis ... often turn out to be false"

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, ho.history-overview, riemann-zeta-function

The title is a quote from a Jim Holt article entitled, "The Riemann zeta conjecture and the laughter of the primes" (p. 47).<sup>1</sup>
His example of a "long-standing conjecture" is the Riemann hypothesis,
and he is cautioning "those who blithely assume the truth of the
Riemann conjecture."

> ***Q***. 
>   What are examples of long-standing conjectures in analysis that turned out to be false?

Is Holt's adverb "often" justified?

---

<sup>1</sup>
Jim Holt.
*When Einstein Walked with Gödel: Excursions to the Edge of Thought*.
Farrar, Straus and Giroux, 2018. pp.36-50.
([NYTimes Review](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/15/books/review/review-when-einstein-walked-with-godel-jim-holt.html).)

Comment: In brief, the adjective is certainly not easily justified. Nor perhaps is there much point in addressing the population of those who _blithely_ assume RH. Looks like an educated non-fiction writer's good-faith construction.

Comment: Somehow it seems that questions isomorphic to this one have been asked a few times on MO....or maybe there is a nuance that I'm missing!

Comment: Re "believing" in RH: what impresses me more than the (seemingly) solemn cautionary declamation of Jim Holt (addressing *whom* exactly?) is the story of the Zagier-Bombieri wager. According to du Sautoy's book *The Music of the Primes*, Don Zagier, number theorist *non pareil*, moved from a position of semi-skepticism/agnosticism about the truth of RH to one of firm belief, after he lost his bet with Bombieri that the first 300 million non-trivial zeroes would yield one off the critical line (he had thought the odds were about 50-50). Of all the conjectures to warn about...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398642/conjectures-or-intuitions-that-turned-out-wrong-in-an-interesting-or-useful-wa

Comment: One can read Holt's essay here: https://books.google.com/books?id=grVTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%22the+riemann+zeta+conjecture+and+the+laughter+of+the+primes%22&source=bl&ots=Mcd42IeqtN&sig=cBoekGG3IwUyYp3uS8XgzSy2FkU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6irXCiL7cAhUNmeAKHSQ8AQgQ6AEwAXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20riemann%20zeta%20conjecture%20and%20the%20laughter%20of%20the%20primes%22&f=false He writes, "Those who blithely assume the truth of the Riemann conjecture should keep in mind an interesting pattern in the history of mathematics: whereas long-standing conjectures in algebra [cont.]

Comment: (like Fermat's theorem) typically turn out to be true, long-standing conjectures in analysis (like the Riemann conjecture) often turn out to be false." Hmm...

Comment: Without seeing the examples Holt is basing this claim on, I more or less agree with paul garrett. My first impression of what's happening here is that the "long-standing conjectures" in analysis that Holt is considering were conjectures from before the formalization revolution and were refuted by "pathological" examples that would not have been accepted prior. But this is more a consequence of the changing meanings of words. This didn't happen (as much) to algebra or number theory.

Comment: [The Bieberbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Branges%27s_theorem) was a long-standing conjecture in analysis which turned out to be true.

Comment: In commenting below Mark S's answer, I'm led to wonder how important Holt's essay is to the content of the question. At the risk of seeming very rude: I'm sort of tempted to ignore the question below the gray box, since I don't imagine Holt has much idea of what he's talking about when he speaks of analysis versus algebra, and there's not much point trying to figure out whether whatever *he thinks* he's saying is justified. Whatever he thinks analysis (and its scope) is, it's likely to be pretty different from what mathematicians understand it to mean.

Comment: Poincare conjecture turned out to be true?

Comment: @Todd Was trying to figure out how to say this without showing outright contempt toward "science journalists".

Comment: @HarryGindi I don't want to dump on science journalists either; there are some very good ones. Holt may be one of them; I don't know his work well enough to say. But the "blithely assume" suggests that he may have gotten a wrong impression somewhere, since conditional statements are just an ordinary uncontroversial part of mathematics. And the comparison between algebra and analysis just sounds a little off to me.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Well to be fair, my last comment was an attempt to obliquely dump on science journalists without appearing impolitic on such an august website as MO =)

Comment: @HarryGindi There's the old Harry I used to know! ;-)

Comment: https://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2009/06/are-there-any-longstanding-conjectures.html has some interesting answers to a similar question, the first comment of which reminds us that [Euler's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture) (1729-1966) was a long-standing generalization of FLT, thus giving pause to the counter-statement about conjectures in algebra.

Comment: Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness (Clay problem) is of course still open but I wonder if predictions about it might have changed direction in the past few years, due to Tao finding blowups in some slightly modified versions.

Answer (score 73):

I don't know about analysis in general, but I think it's definitely fair to say "often" in functional analysis. My feeling is that we have a solid, thorough, elegant body of theory which usually leads to positive solutions rather quickly, when they exist. (The Kadison-Singer problem is a recent exception which required radically new tools for a positive solution.) Problems that stick around for a long time tend to do so not because there's a complicated positive solution but because there's a complicated counterexample. That's a gross overgeneralization but I think there's some truth to it.

The first examples I can think of are:

- every separable Banach space has the approximation property and has a Schauder basis (counterexample by Enflo)
- every bounded linear operator on a Banach space has a nontrivial closed invariant subspace (counterexamples by Enflo and Read)
- every infinite dimensional Banach space has an infinite dimensional subspace which admits an unconditional Schauder basis (counterexample by Gowers and Maurey)
- every infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ is isomorphic to $X \oplus \mathbb{R}$; if $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, each linearly homeomorphic to a subspace of the other, then they are linearly homeomorphic (counterexample by Gowers)

I can't resist also mentioning some examples that I was involved with.

- Dixmier's problem: every prime C*-algebra is primitive (counterexample by me)
- Naimark's problem: if a C*-algebra has only one irreducible representation up to unitary equivalence, then it is isomorphic to $K(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$ (counterexample by Akemann and me)
- every pure state on $B(l^2)$ is pure on some masa (counterexample by Akemann and me)
- every automorphism of the Calkin algebra is inner (counterexample by Phillips and me)

The last three require extra set-theoretic axioms, so the correct statement is that if ordinary set theory is consistent, then it is consistent that these counterexamples exist. Presumably all three are independent of the usual axioms of set theory, but this is only known of the last one, where the consistency of a positive solution was proved by Farah.

Comment: this is a very nice collection of examples! But I'd wager that these are all wildly out-of-scope for the actual comment of the writer. Maybe they are indeed relevant to the OP, but this may be one of those times where the (educated?) layperson's question only accidentally stimulates genuine mathematical discussion. Not a bad thing! :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: I agree with your comment.  I did try to be clear that my answer was specifically about functional analysis ...

Comment: @paulgarrett My guess is that RH is also out-of-scope for the writer, in terms of any real understanding of its import. (The only difference is that he's heard of it.) So I'd say anything is fair game. Your answer and Nik's are good ones.

Comment: I think this answer is likely true and certainly very useful, in that it can productively modify one's overall view/approach to functional analysis. Thanks, Nik!

Comment: @JonBannon and Nik: perhaps this is why there is the free group factor _problem_ rather than the free group factor _conjecture_ :) Although I note that we have the Connes embedding _problem_ yet the QWEP _conjecture_ ...

Comment: @YemonChoi: if it were the free group factor "conjecture" which would it be, isomorphic or non-isomorphic? My limited exposure hasn't given me any intuition for which way it should go.

Comment: Nik: that was sort of my point :) Kadison prudently left it as a question, rather than committing to a conjecture. (Parallels with K-S here, I guess.) I have no idea what the answer should be or what the experts think the answer should be!

Comment: Kadison?  Somehow I thought this went back to Murray and von Neumann ...

Comment: @NikWeaver and YemonChoi: Kadison personally told a group of us at lunch that von Neumann asked him the question. I can't recall if it appears in the MvN papers, does it?

Answer (score 48):

If RH is "analysis", then surely Littlewood's 1914 theorem that $\pi(x)$ (the prime counting function) and $\mathrm{li}(x)$ (the logarithmic integral) alternate in size infinitely often... despite all numerical evidence at the time indicating that $\pi(x)\le \mathrm{li}(x)$.

Part of the point is that the first reversal only occurs at a rather large number. S. Skewes, a student of Littlewood, gave an effective bound in 1933 assuming RH, and a better one in 1955 unconditionally, ... both of which were ridiculously large numbers. (Just search on "Skewes' number" to see details...)

Similarly, some regularities in the behavior of $\zeta(s)$ do only "kick in" when $\log\log(\Im(s))$ is large... which we will never appraise numerically. Dunno whether this is analysis, but it is fairly genuine mathematics of *some* sort, and may perhaps illustrate the possibility that phenomena do occur outside the range of direct (with or without computers, quantum or not) observation (by humans). In particular, even sophisticated numerical simulation cannot reach large $\log\log T$, so the conclusions that we draw (e.g., A. Odlyzko's and other's computation of zeros of zeta up to human-enormous heights) could potentially be ... meaningless?

(In a different way, the issues raised by Nik Weaver are somewhat similar, in that they arise from palpable issues, but whose abstractions inadvertently involve phenomenological entities surprisingly beyond our easy capacity.)

Comment: I love this phrase: "phenomenological entities surprisingly beyond our easy capacity"!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, :)

Answer (score 30):

The Riemann hypothesis is a conjecture in *both* analysis and number theory. Someone who tries to undermine it necessarily has to ignore the latter part or to declare it irrelevant. I am not suggesting that it is true (I do not know), only that it becomes more plausible when you take into account that its violation implies a sort of conspiracy between primes and that there are function field analogs which are actually proven.

Once we look at the conjecture from this angle it is arguably unique, and no examples from analysis make a big point.

Answer (score 9):

In another vein, taking the question seriously, etc.:

Let's consider the intermediate value theorem: a (continuous?) function takes every intermediate value, etc. Obviously true, when we believe that functions are things whose graphs we can (easily) draw. But, false, with introduction of not-continuous functions. But, then, again, it's ok when we add that qualifier.

Similarly, the mean value theorem: if $u'=0$, then $u$ is constant. Obviously true. Well, problems with saying what the derivative of a not-so-nice function is... distributions/generalized functions... But, in the end, if a distribution has derivative(s) zero, it is (integrate-against) a constant.

Whew!

Similarly, we can go through dialectics about integrals...

Perhaps even more substantially, the early 20th-century Polish school of set theory and real analysis looked at many situations where a hypothetical simplicity of description of subsets of $\mathbb R$ really needed the continuum hypothesis... or more. I'm insufficiently expert to discuss those things, but am aware of them.

Answer (score 7):

With $\mu(k)$ is the Möbius function, the [Mertens conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture) states that the Mertens function

$$M(n)=\sum_{1\le k\le n} \mu(k)$$

is bounded <strike>below</strike> **above** as
$$|M(n)|\le \sqrt{n}$$

The conjecture lasted 100 years, from 1885 to 1985, when it started to crumble with the work of Andrew Odlyzko and Herman te Riele.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good example inasmuch as it relates to RH, but it'd be weird to consider this as "belonging to analysis" (even if it's not obviously not analysis). I can't tell if this is the sort of answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: Agreed.  Reading Holt's (otherwise well-versed) article, it might be an example *he* had in mind.  But there's another question lurking in Holt's essay... Are conjectures like Broadway plays, obeying Gott's Copernican principle?  Are long-standing conjectures more likely to be unproven in the distant future?

Comment: Despite all the negativity in my comments in this thread, I agree that Holt's article is stimulating and well written. Regarding that question... yes, maybe, I guess?? Feels like an angels on the head of a pin question. :-)

Comment: Was I wrong to read this as a fine retort to Holt’s flip side that “long-standing conjectures in [¿not-analysis?] (like Fermat's theorem) typically turn out to be true”? (BTW: bounded *above*.)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler thanks, embarrassed for the mistake.  I suspect, without any evidence, that Holt might have used "analysis" as in "analytic number theory."  To me and my naivety, Littlewood's theorem mentioned by paul garrett and Odlyzko and te Riele's theorem are of the same character, but are arguably *not* analysis as in Nik Weaver's answer along with paul's other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fuglede's conjecture was open for 30 years (1974-2004) only to be proven false by T. Tao for dimensions $d\geq 5$ with a [counter-example](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306134)  arising from a set with an exponential orthonormal basis (a *spectrum*) in a finite abelian group which does not tile by translation. Interestingly, the largest dimension for which the conjecture is open now is $d=2$.