# Heuristic model for Lehmer pairs?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, heuristics

[Rodgers and Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05914) proved that the [De Bruijn–Newman constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Newman_constant) $\Lambda$ is non-negative.  The study of $\Lambda$ goes back at least to Lehmer's paper, [On the roots of the Riemann zeta-function](http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/117/5833-11511_2006_Article_BF02401102.pdf), whose Figure 1 illustrates the striking phenomenon that the Riemann hypothesis sometimes "looks close to being violated," in the sense that if the curve in Figure 1 were to turn around before crossing the horizontal axis, then RH would fail, and it visually appears to be "dangerously close" to doing so.

I am wondering if there is a plausible heuristic model for Lehmer pairs which treats them as random variables, and which predicts the "probability of a violation of RH" in the above sense.  Such a model might give us heuristic confidence in RH, if it lets us say something along the following lines: "If the process really were random, then we would expect a violation of RH by the time the imaginary part of $\zeta(s)$ reached such-and-such a value, but we have calculated the zeros out beyond that without observing a violation.  Therefore there must be a ‘reason’ that the violations are not occurring."

A related MO question is [Heuristic argument for the Riemann Hypothesis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339540) but the above question does not seem to be addressed there.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but note that Alexander Dobner (a former student of prof. Tao), has published a simpler proof of the non-negativity of the De Bruijn-Newman constant. It also quite elegantly extends to a wide range of Dirichlet L-series. https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05142

Answer (score 5):

Assume RH and let $\rho_j = \frac12 + i \gamma_j$ be the $j$th critical zero
with positive imaginary part.
The number of such zeros with imaginary part in
$[0,T]$ is $N(T) = \frac{1}{2\pi} T\log(T/(2\pi e)) + O(\log T)$.

Thus, the "unfolded zeros"
$$
\tilde{\gamma}_j := \frac{1}{2\pi} \gamma_j \log(\gamma_j)
$$

satisfy:  $\tilde{\gamma}_{j+1} - \tilde{\gamma}_j$ is 1 on average.
The "GUE Hypothesis" implies that, in the limit as $T\to\infty$,
the distribution of  $\tilde{\gamma}_{j+1} - \tilde{\gamma}_j$
is the same as the distribution (in the limit $N\to\infty$) of the
(similarly rescaled) eigenvalue neighbor gaps of random matrices from the Gaussian Unitary
Ensemble of $N\times N$ matrices.  Numerical calculations of Ozlyzko
support that conjecture.

The PDF of the GUE nearest neighbor distribution is well-approximated by the "Wigner surmise"
$\frac{32}{\pi^2} x^2 e^{-\frac{4}{\pi}x^2}$.  Thus, at least conjecturally,
we know exactly how often there should be extremely small gaps between zeros
of the zeta function.

The official definition of "Lehmer pair" quantifies how small the
gap has to be, and you can use the GUE Hypothesis to predict the
frequency of Lehmer pairs.  But in terms of justifying the statement
"RH is barely true", it strikes me as sufficient to note that the
distribution of neighbor gaps is (conjecturally) supported on all
of $(0,\infty)$.

To address what appears to be the point of the original question, note that
"barely true" does not mean "likely to be false".  The random eigenvalues
from the GUE are all real.  So, the analogue of RH is known to be true in
that context, and yet it also is "barely true".   And, the process is
random, but not random in a way that suggests RH might fail.

Comment: "...and you can use the GUE Hypothesis to predict the frequency of Lehmer pairs..."

Suppose the GUE hypothesis is indeed proven, would that imply there are infinitely many Lehmer pairs? This 2018 blog post by prof. Tao https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/01/20/lehmer-pairs-and-gue/ seems to suggest such a conclusion can't be drawn yet.

Comment: @Agno: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but isn't Tao's blog post exactly an argument for GUE => infinitely many Lehmer pairs?

Comment: What Tao's 2018 blog post says is that assuming GUE for pair-, 3-, and 4-correlations gives infinitely many Lehmer pairs.  (In a comment it says how to avoid 4-correlation.) So, assuming all of the GUE Hypothesis is sufficient to conclude infinitely many Lehmer pairs.  Tao suggests that only assuming pair correlation is not sufficient. Presumably assuming only the predicted nearest neighbor spacing is also insufficient -- although the counterexample would involve some unlikely clumping of zeros.

Comment: For the layman who I am, can this GUE hypothesis be seen as an analogue of the central limit theorem? If yes, can we reasonably expect a similar proof?

Comment: The GUE statistics are in a universality class, meaning there are general features of a system which tell you to expect GUE statistics.  The Gaussian/normal distribution is also in a universality class.  But, the nature of those universality classes is different.  It would be unreasonable to expect a similar proof, and also unreasonable to draw any inference to the fact that both have a "universality" to them.  So, no, the GUE Hypothesis is not an analogue of the central limit theorem.

Comment: Just a thought: the "GUE Hypothesis" is, if true, probably a very delicate one and will only be valid at $\Lambda=0$ (i.e. no $t$-distortion, RH true). 
Rationale:
1) the tiniest negative $t$-distortion will always induce a complex zero, hence clash with the Hermitian matrix in GUE that can only have real eigenvalues. 
2) the tiniest positive $t$-distortion will have the real zeros eventually evolve into an arithmetic progression (at extremely high $T$), implying Lehmer pairs must be finite for $t>0$ and it also clashes with the inherent randomness of the GUE eigenvalue gap distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difficulty lies in having a precise definition of Lehmer pair.  Lehmer did not make one, but merely exhibited an example of a pair of consecutive zeros with a very small gap, such that the maximum of the Hardy function $Z(T)$ in between was very close to zero.  (If $Z(t)$ has a negative local max or positive local min, then RH is false.). Csordas, Smith, and Varga, in *Lehmer pairs of zeros, the de Bruijn-Newman constant, and the Riemann Hypothesis*, did give a precise definition, and showed that a Lehmer pair gives a lower bound on $\Lambda$.  Their definition is somewhat technical, and depends not just on the zeros being close but also on what other nearby zeros are doing.

Comment: FWIW, Wikipedia has a pretty simple definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_pair

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes it's a single inequality, but it involves every zero of $\zeta(s)$, not just the two in the pair.  I would love to see a simple heuristic.  With this goal in mind, in 'Lehmer pairs revisited', I defined 'strong Lehmer pairs' and showed every strong Lehmer pair is a Lehmer pair.  The hope was that with a more useful definition, it might be possible to show there are infinitely many.

Comment: @Stopple A few months ago, I've read your nice paper about the Strong Lehmer pair definition and used it to compute all Strong Lehmer pairs amongst the first 500K non-trivial zeros (there are 3583 pairs). In case people are interested, the csv-data can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zoxq40LJt87pvl7pN4C1kh-sXkBXdbUP/view?usp=sharing with layout: $n, \Im(\rho_n), n+1, \Im(\rho_{n+1}), \Delta(\Im(\rho)), 8 < x < 42/5,  2\Im(\rho_n), 2\Im(\rho_{n+1}), 2\Delta(\Im(\rho))$. Computations were done in ARB.

Comment: @Agno Cool!  What is ARB?

Comment: @Stopple ARB is an impressive C library for arbitrary-precision ball arithmetic (https://arblib.org). It has just celebrated its 10th anniversary: https://fredrikj.net/blog/2022/04/arb-is-10/ It has for instance been used in the Polymath 15 project bringing the DBN upper bound down to 0.22, and also more recently by Dave Platt and Tim Trudgian to verify the Riemann hypothesis to record height (bringing the DBN constant to < 0.2).